# Odd compiling error with generic classes and lists

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

So I have came across a weird compiling error when using a generic class that has a List (or Map or Set, etc) as an attribute.

The compiling error occurs while trying to iterate (using a foreach) the List:

```
Sample.java:11: error: incompatible types
        for (String string : s.getStringList()) {
  required: String
  found:    Object
```

Just to be clear, **I know there's a simple workaround for this problem, but I want to understand what is wrong with the code**

Following is the sample I have created:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Sample<T> {

    public List<String> stringList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample s = new Sample();

        // Why this doesn't work?
        for (String string : s.getStringList()) {

        }

        // Why does both of the following work?
        List<String> newList = s.getStringList();

        Sample<Object> s2 = new Sample<>();
        for (String string : s2.getStringList()) {

        }

    }

    public List<String> getStringList() {
        return stringList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These lines

```
Sample s = new Sample();

// Why this doesn't work?
for (String string : s.getStringList()) {

}
```

do not work because you are using the *raw* form of the `Sample` class.  When you use the raw form of the class, *all* generics in the class, even unrelated generics, have type erasure performed.  That means that `getStringList` now just returns a `List` of `Object`s, not a `List<String>` of `String`s.

This part of Java was introduced with Generics in Java 1.5 so that the old version of classes that now use generics would be backwards compatible.  That way, something that iterates over `List`, which had to use `Object` before, still can use `Object` by using the raw form of `List`.

The [JLS, Section 4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) deals with raw types:

> More precisely, a raw type is defined to be one of:
>
> - The reference type that is formed by taking the name of a generic type declaration without an accompanying type argument list.

and

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the **erasure of its type** in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

(emphasis mine)

The reasoning:

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.

Comment: Very well written answer, thank you! Explained every aspect of the problem, with references and all. +1 for you, sir

Answer (score 3):

You're using the raw `Sample` type, and the compiler thus assumes that you don't care about generic types, even for variables not declared as raw types inside this object. It's a strange rule, but it's how it is. You shouldn't use raw types if you care about generics. As soon as you use a raw type, all its members are also taken as raw types by the compiler.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: ECJ works like that too. *Very* unintuitive behaviour, to be honest...